# git -C /var/git/plexus.git log > Test.txt

Tags: java, linux, git-log

Here is my problem: I want to create a git log file staying outside the repository folder and save it as `TestfromShell.txt`.

I have git command

```
git -C /var/git/plexus.git log > Test.txt
```

for linux machine. I want to execute this command from Java, but every time I execute this command from Java, it says:

```
Command to be executed :git -C /var/git/plexus.git log > Test.txt
Error:
fatal: ambiguous argument '>': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Java code:

```
command="git -C /var/git/plexus.git log > Test.txt"; 
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: Running the command in Java doesn't interpret things the same as in your shell. `>` is interpreted as that symbol, not a redirection.

Comment: how could I possibly log all the data into Test.txt from java ??

Comment: Yes. It's in the answers of the duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks so much for :)